# source a setDomainEnv.cmd file in windows 7

Tags: java, weblogic11g

When i read how to change password for weblogic, I have said to source the setDomainEnv.cmd file.

I need to know how to source it? How does it differ just by go the directory which reside the cmd file and type setDomainEnv.cmd in command prompt and press enter. Is this way is what called execute the cmd file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, source the setDomainEnv.cmd means execute the file from the directory. It is simply to set the required environment variables.